# rewrite rules in wordpress are not updated after flushing

Tags: php, wordpress, url, url-rewriting

I have added this function to rewrite some rules in wordpress:

```
add_action( 'init', 'my_add_rewrite_rules' );   

function mydid_add_rewrite_rules() {  

 global $wp_rewrite;    

 add_rewrite_rule(....);        
 .... Added some rewrite rules here...

 $wp_rewrite->flush_rules();

}
```

So far, everything works perfect.

After browsing the urls, I supposed that the database containing the rewrite rules was updated and I have commented the line:

```
// commented the line because this is an "expensive" action and I suppose that the 
// database is already updated
// $wp_rewrite->flush_rules();
```

However, after commenting, the url rewrite does not work.
Why? 
Wasn't the database already updated?

p.s. I can not flush from the wp admin panel because of some theme's constrains...

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, found the problem...

There was another "flush rewrite rules" somewhere else, which actually overriden the database. I commented it as well and everything works fine now.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use different hooks for the rewrites & flush:

```
function mydid_add_rewrite_rules() {  
    global $wp_rewrite;    
    // add_rewrite_rule(....);        
    // .... Added some rewrite rules here...
}
add_action( 'generate_rewrite_rules', 'mydid_add_rewrite_rules' ); 

function mydid_flush_rewrite_rules() {
    global $wp_rewrite;
    $wp_rewrite->flush_rules();
}
add_action( 'init', 'mydid_flush_rewrite_rules');
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. "add_action( 'init', 'mydid_flush_rewrite_rules');" would flush the rules each time an "init" happens, wouldn't it? I want to avoid flushing each time because it is expensive. P.S. I want to flush only once I update manually some rules --> as a result the database is updated --> then to comment the '$wp_rewrite->flush_rules();' till next time I want to change some rules manually within the code....

Comment: Then add the `$wp_rewrite->flush_rules();` to your function which updates the database or manually just re-save your permalink structure in Settings->Permalinks after you made your rewrite changes.

Comment: Doesnt $wp_rewrite->flush_rules(); update the database? See my initial function... Shouldn't it be updated? If it is updated, why isnt it working AFTER I comment it...? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The solution I found was this:

```
global $wp_rewrite;
$wp_rewrite->flush_rules();
$wp_rewrite->init();
```